# Trace of a real, symmetric positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a naive question about the trace of a real, symmetric positive semi-definite matrix:

> Does the trace of a real, symmetric positive semi-definite matrix have to be larger than $1$?

I know that all the eigenvalues of the matrix must be strictly non-negative, but does the sum of all the non-negative eigenvalues must be larger than $1$?

Comment: the trace of the zeros matrix is zero.

Comment: Just a clarification. From the context, I can understand that you are talking about real symmetric **positive** semi - definite matrices, right?

Comment: @thanasissdr Yes of course, sorry I forgot to mention that. I have a follow-up question: what if you know that the entries of the matrix are larger than 1? does that change anything?

Comment: @thanasissdr Thanks a lot for your help man! really appreciate it !

Comment: If $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, the trace of $\epsilon I_n$ for $\epsilon>0$ is $n\epsilon$, which can be made arbitrarily small (given a fixed $n$) as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$.

Comment: @JackShi If the matrix $A$ has at least one entry greater than $1$, then it is certain that the spectral radius $\rho(A)$ of the matrix will be greater than $1$. So, we have that the trace of the matrix $A$ will be always greater than $1$. You may check [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367078/spectral-radius-of-a-real-symmetric-positive-semi-definite-matrix?lq=1).

Comment: @thanasissdr got it. Again thank you so much! without this, my entire proof will not hold. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not necessary. A non-trivial counterexample:

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0.26 & 0.05 \\ 0.05 & 0.01 \end{bmatrix},$$
which is clearly a real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix (actually, it's positive definite).

This can be verified by computing its eigenvalues, which are: $\lambda_1  = 0.0004$ and $\lambda_2 = 0.2696$. Clearly, the trace of $A$ is smaller than $1$.

Comment: got it. thanks a lot!

Comment: @JackShi No problem. You're welcome!